# Ayuda con aplicación Android y mapas

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una App en Android que utiliza mapas. Pero obtengo un error al compilar que dice lo siguiente:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{teamtreehouse.com.iamhere/teamtreehouse.com.iamhere.MapsActivity}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)'
>   on a null object reference

Esto se da cuando declaro una segunda variable mMap2 (si yo uso solamente mMap la aplicación funciona bien) que la necesito para poder añadir diferentes ventanas de información a un marcador determinado.

Pego el codigo a ver si alguien me puede ayudar a entender porque la aplicación hace crash cuando yo declaro esta segunda variable, ya que necesitare crear varias.

```
package teamtreehouse.com.iamhere;

import android.content.IntentSender;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMapOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements
        GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
        GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener,
        LocationListener {

    public static final String TAG = MapsActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    /*
     * Define a request code to send to Google Play services
     * This code is returned in Activity.onActivityResult
     */
    private final static int CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;

    private GoogleMap mMap; // Might be null if Google Play services APK is not available.

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        setUpMapIfNeeded();

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

        // Create the LocationRequest object
        mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
                .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY)
                .setInterval(10 * 1000)        // 10 seconds, in milliseconds
                .setFastestInterval(1 * 1000); // 1 second, in milliseconds
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Sets up the map if it is possible to do so (i.e., the Google Play services APK is correctly
     * installed) and the map has not already been instantiated.. This will ensure that we only ever
     * call {@link #setUpMap()} once when {@link #mMap} is not null.
     * <p/>
     * If it isn't installed {@link SupportMapFragment} (and
     * {@link com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView MapView}) will show a prompt for the user to
     * install/update the Google Play services APK on their device.
     * <p/>
     * A user can return to this FragmentActivity after following the prompt and correctly
     * installing/updating/enabling the Google Play services. Since the FragmentActivity may not
     * have been completely destroyed during this process (it is likely that it would only be
     * stopped or paused), {@link #onCreate(Bundle)} may not be called again so we should call this
     * method in {@link #onResume()} to guarantee that it will be called.
     */
    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }






    }



    /**
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case, we
     * just add a marker near Africa.
     * <p/>
     * This should only be called once and when we are sure that {@link #mMap} is not null.
     */
    private void setUpMap() {




//        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
//                .position(new LatLng(-27.581992, -66.314411))
//                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.acupuncture))
//                .title("Hotel"));

        GoogleMap mMapf = null;
        mMapf.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-27.583069, -66.313380))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("OSDE"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng( -27.581094, -66.313418))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Otro Hotel"));

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng( -27.585490, -66.305299))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Restaurante Viejo Lobo"));





        mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

                View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.info_window ,null);

                TextView date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
                TextView comment = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textView);
                ImageView image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.hotel_uno);




                return view;
            }
        });




    }


    private void handleNewLocation(Location location) {
        Log.d(TAG, location.toString());

        double currentLatitude = location.getLatitude();
        double currentLongitude = location.getLongitude();

        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude);

        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(currentLatitude, currentLongitude)).title("Localizacion Actual"));
        MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions()
                .position(latLng)
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Hola! Usted se encuentra en este punto.");
        mMap.addMarker(options);
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(latLng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (location == null) {
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
        }
        else {
            handleNewLocation(location);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
        /*
         * Google Play services can resolve some errors it detects.
         * If the error has a resolution, try sending an Intent to
         * start a Google Play services activity that can resolve
         * error.
         */
        if (connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
            try {
                // Start an Activity that tries to resolve the error
                connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, CONNECTION_FAILURE_RESOLUTION_REQUEST);
                /*
                 * Thrown if Google Play services canceled the original
                 * PendingIntent
                 */
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                // Log the error
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            /*
             * If no resolution is available, display a dialog to the
             * user with the error.
             */
            Log.i(TAG, "Location services connection failed with code " + connectionResult.getErrorCode());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        handleNewLocation(location);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

La instancia del mapa es nula:

```
 GoogleMap mMapf = null;
```

nunca vas a poder agregar un marcador si la instancia del mapa es nula:

```
GoogleMap mMapf = null;
mMapf.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
        .position(new LatLng(-27.583069, -66.313380))
        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
        .title("OSDE"));
```

Por esta razón tienes el mensaje de error:

> NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker
>   com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions)'
>   on a null object reference

**Importante: No debes crear varias instancias del Mapa**, usa la instancia del mapa de la variable  `private GoogleMap mMap;` dentro del método `setUpMap()` :

```
 private void setUpMap() {

        //GoogleMap mMapf = null;
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(new LatLng(-27.583069, -66.313380))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("OSDE"));
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

#### En realidad no se agregan diferentes ventanas de información para todos los marcadores, la ventana de información se crea a partir de los datos especificados en el marcador, mediante el método [showInfoWindow()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#public-methods) .

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/infowindows?hl=es

Te doy una idea para lograr lo que deseas,

Crea una lista de marcadores:

```
List<Marker> lstMarcadores =  new ArrayList<>();
```

Crea los marcadores :

```
Marker marker;
marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng( -27.585490, -66.305299))
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.airport))
                .title("Restaurante"));
```

Agrega cada uno de los marcadores marcador a la lista de marcadores:

```
lstMarcadores.add(marker);
```

Teniendo todos los marcadores en tu lista puedes abrir la ventana de información  dependiendo del indice del elemento guardado en la lista:

```
lstMarcadores.get(marcadorSeleccionado).showInfoWindow()
```

Entonces al dar clic en alguno de los elementos de tu mapa y basado en su indice podras mostrar su información.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: El problema es que si uso una sola instancia (mMap) veo el mismo infoWindow en todo los marcadores. y necesito mostrar datos diferentes en cada uno de ellos.

Comment: Yo necesito que cada marcador muestre un infoWindow distinto y no que todos los marcadores me muestren el mismo hotel... (por dar un ejemplo)

Comment: Hola Gonzalo, entiendo lo que deseas realizar, tienes una lista de objetos que contengan el titulo y geolocalización que desees agregar a los marcadores? Porque si no es así vas a tener que agregar varias lineas de código para cada marcador.

Comment: En realidad tengo un layout (otro xml) desde donde traigo las imagenes y los nombres de los lugares. Justamente me interesaba ver como hacer para agregar esas varias lineas de codigo a cada marker... ando un poco perdido.

Comment: En efecto como usted dice la información viene de los markers. El problema se da cuando uno intenta poner una imagen a esas infowindow o hacerlos un poco mas complejo. Aquí hay que utilizar una función (que es la que esta puesta en el código arriba llamada:  mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter y aqui el problema porque setInfoWindowAdapter es la única forma que tengo de hacer infowindows un poco mas complejos y elaborados. El metodo que usted me da me sirve lo use y lo probé pero termino cayendo en el mismo problema...  ya que el unico objeto que me recibe es justamente mMap...

Comment: A lo que voy es que aunque utilice listas o arrays de objetos no tengo forma de ponerles una imagen a los infowindow y mucho menos cosas mas elaboradas como sistemas de calificación por estrellas y cosas que solo podría traer de un XML que tengo creado tambien en mi proyecto donde estan justamente las imagenes y los datos con los que deseo trabajar en esos infowindow.

cc/@Elenasys